# Node-Red Serial connection rx tx Raspberry Pi and Arduino

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, node-red, serial-communication

I'm currently working on my Raspberry Pi with Node-red.
I want to have a serial connection between my Pi and Arduino.
I connected my Raspberry pi and Arduino uno over the rx and tx pins.

[image: Serial input in Node-Red]

I can send data from my Arduino to my Pi over the pins.

Arduino Code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  //Arduino to Raspberry Pi
  Serial.println("test");  
  delay(1000);
}
```

I receive the data on my Pi

BUT as soon as I want to send data from my Pi to the Arduino, it doesn't work.

[image: Serial output in Node-Red]

Arduino Code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  //Raspberry Pi to Arduino
  if (Serial.available() > 0){
    int x = Serial.read();
    Serial.println(x);
  }
}
```

Now, if I press the inject button which send the string "hello" in Node-Red there is no output in the serial monitor on the Arduino.

If i use that code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int x = Serial.read();
  Serial.println(x);
}
```

The Serial Monitor displays -1 all the time. But if I press the inject button in Node-Red there appears some numbers not greater than 255.

[image: Serial Monitor]

I hoped to see the String "hello".

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Your monitor displaying -1 is perfectly normal, it's because since Serial connection are synchronous, they send data continuously in order to not lose synchronisation. So when you setup the arduino using `serial.Begin(9600)`you initiate a connection, so they send data to each other, even though the proper data communication hasn't started yet. See rs-232 on wiki if you want more info

You're reading x as an int on your arduino.
"hello" is not really an int :p 
try using `String x =Serial.Read();`instead